# Function always positive: Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have a function $v : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which describes the norm of the velocity of an object moving under gravitational forces. As the object describes a closed period path, hence the function $v$ is periodic, of period 1 let's say, and always positive, as it is the norm of the velocity.

I was thinking and couldn't find an answer, what is, if there exists, a pattern of the Fourier series coefficients.

If someone knows the answer that would be great and an explanation would be even more appreciated. Thank you!

Marius

Comment: you could translate the orbit to center around zero and then parameterize using usual methods?

Comment: the question comes from developing numerically via action-minimization N-body choreographies and it turned out that working with $(x,y)$ coordinates is not working very well.  Thanks for the recommendation, though!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for being hasty in posting and then actually answering my own question. If the Fourier Series is under the form $$v(t) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty[a_k\cos(2\pi k)+b_k\sin(2\pi k)]$$ then what is needed is just that for $a_0$ to be greater than the sum of modules of the other Fourier coefficients. This ensures that the sum is always positive.

Sorry for posting so quickly a question.

Although, I would be happy to hear other answers! :)

Comment: That's a sufficient condition, but certainly not necessary. For example, consider a "square wave" function which oscillates between the values $1$ and $2$ (so certainly it's positive everywhere), and for simplicity assume it's an even function, so the $b_k$'s are all zero. Then $a_0 = 3/2$, but the sum of the absolute values of the other $|a_k|$'s is infinite.

Comment: P.S. I don't know a necessary and sufficient condition. Interesting question!

Comment: Yes, I was almost sure it is not necessary, but it solves what I was looking for at the moment. Definitely if some fixes $a_0$, the problem becomes more interesting.